# From Python 3.3 to Python 2.6

Tags: python, version

I have Python 3.3 installed on my machine, but since I would like to use a program which requires only Python 2.6, how can I do to move from Python 3.3 to Python 2.6

I am using ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `python` instead of `python3`

```
# Python2
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 30 2016, 18:31:42) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 

# Python3
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov  7 2016, 17:25:58) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Or declare in your Python files,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: `python` vs `python3` is entirely dependent on how it was installed... not a general solution. shebang is good, but only for *nix

Comment: @Aaron, thx for pointing out this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create different environments for using both versions of python, 
a quick guide of how to do it is here:
https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/

Alternatively: https://conda.io/docs/py2or3.html

Comment: I'm a personal fan of conda..

Comment: Thank you for your Quick reply